# How to override core model in custom module for SOAP & REST API?

Tags: magento-2.1.7, override-model

I want override `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShippingAssignmentBuilder`model only for Soap & REST API.

I have tried following:

**SOAP API:**

> app\code\AR\Sales\etc\webapi_soap\di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShippingAssignmentBuilder" type="AR\Sales\Model\Order\ShippingAssignmentBuilder"/>
```

**REST API:**

> app\code\AR\Sales\etc\webapi_rest\di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShippingAssignmentBuilder" type="AR\Sales\Model\Order\ShippingAssignmentBuilder"/>
```

**Model File:**

> app\code\AR\Sales\Model\Order\ShippingAssignmentBuilder.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright Â© 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace AR\Sales\Model\Order;

use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory;

/**
 * Class ShippingAssignmentBuilder
 * @package Magento\Sales\Model\Order
 */
class ShippingAssignmentBuilder extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShippingAssignmentBuilder
{


    /**
     * @return ShippingAssignmentInterface[]|null
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $shippingAssignments = null;
        ...
        ...
        ...

        return $shippingAssignments;
    }
}
```

Model is successfully override in my custom module but below data is not getting

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution myself via **After Plugin** method:

**SOAP API:**

> app\code\AR\Sales\etc\webapi_soap\di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShippingAssignmentBuilder">
     <plugin name="shippingAssignmentBuilder_create" type="AR\Sales\Model\Plugin\ShippingAssignmentBuilder"/>
</type>
```

**REST API:**

> app\code\AR\Sales\etc\webapi_rest\di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShippingAssignmentBuilder">
     <plugin name="shippingAssignmentBuilder_create" type="AR\Sales\Model\Plugin\ShippingAssignmentBuilder"/>
</type>
```

**Model file:**

Now create `ShippingAssignmentBuilder.php` in folder `app\code\AR\Sales\Model\Plugin\`

After plugin method is called by adding prefix ‘after’ to the method name and setting first letter of original method to capital (**afterCreate**).

```
<?php

namespace AR\Sales\Model\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;

class ShippingAssignmentBuilder
{

    /**
     * Create shipping assignment
     *
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShippingAssignmentBuilder $subject
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface[] $resultOrder
     * @return Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface[]|null
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */

    public function afterCreate(\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ShippingAssignmentBuilder $subject, $shippingAssignments)
    {
        ...
        ...
        ...

        return $shippingAssignments; 
    }   
}
```

After run compiler command:

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```